# Abreviatura da palavra "versão"

Tags: abreviações

O português não é a minha língua materna. Procurei a abreviatura da palavra "versão" sem sucesso.

Já vi "Vers" mas vi-o usado para "verso".

Qual é a abreviatura para a palavra "versão"? É para um documento legal.

Obrigado

Comment: Em programas e jogos, vejo muito *v.* sendo usado; ex.: *Minecraft v. 1.12*. Porém, é possível ser originalmente do inglês.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com as regras para abreviaturas listadas pelo [Toda Matéria](https://www.todamateria.com.br/abreviaturas/), que incluem

> Primeira sílaba + primeira letra da segunda sílaba (se for consoante) + ponto

a abreviatura de "versão" seria **vers.**, mas vale notar que não consta nas listas que verifiquei (como a da [Academia Brasileira de Letras](https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/reducoes)).

A opção "**v.**", comentada pelo Schilive provavelmente seria compreendida em certos contextos e seria aceitável ao menos informalmente, mas também não parece ser estabelecida em português.